# Commutativity of the Cross Product in Singular Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Massey's *Singular Homology Theory* claims that if $X,Y$ are topological spaces, $G_1,G_2$ abelain groups, and $u \in H^p(X;G_1)$ and $v \in H^q(Y;G_2)$, then $$t^*(u \times v) = (-1)^{pq}v \times u,$$
where $t : Y \times X \to X \times Y$ is given by $(y,x) \mapsto (x,y)$. This identity doesn't make sense to me, since the left hand side is an element of $H^{p+q}(Y \times X;G_1 \otimes G_2)$ while the right hand side is an element of $H^{p+q}(Y \times X; G_2 \otimes G_1)$. Am I missing something or do we need to compose with a homomorphism $G_1 \otimes G_2 \to G_2 \otimes G_1$ somewhere to make this work?

Comment: Those tensor products are canonically isomorphic, hence the corresponding cohomology groups are as well.

Comment: Yes, you have to to that. There is a canonical isomorphism $\phi : G_1 \otimes G_2 \to G_2 \otimes G_1$.  Can you prove it now?